# Large images not rendering with Webpack + React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to render an image from my image folder to a React project using Webpack. I notice that for smaller photos (i.e. physically smaller dimensions, which I imagine means a smaller file size), the photo loads. However, for larger photos, nothing renders on screen except for a placeholder seen here. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPcnE.png)

I suspect this may be due to an incorrect Webpack configuration. The photo import and rendering itself is working, because smaller photos do render. Specifically, I suspect this may be an issue with the "file-loader" clause in Webpack.

Below is my Webpack setup:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const config = {
  entry: __dirname + '/imports/layouts/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".css"]
  },

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: "styles.css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ],


  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              // you can specify a publicPath here
              // by default it use publicPath in webpackOptions.output
              publicPath: '../'
            }
          },
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
    }, {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|jpg|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
    }]
  },


};

module.exports = config;
```

In case it may be useful, below is how I am rendering the image in React.

```
import photo from '../../images/sample_photo.jpg';

import './sample.css';

    export default class Sample extends Component {
      render () {
        return (
        <img src={photo}></img>
         )
     } }
```

The image itself is rendering as "24d565c81ae689a281aabb01ad3208db.jpg" in the browser, rather than "sample_photo.jpg" for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your webpack config, you have defined `module` objects twice.

So your 2nd `module` configuration will override the 1st. Since `file-loader` is not mentioned in your 2nd `module`, once your `url-loader` limit (100,000) exceeds file will not be parsed.

Also, `url-loader` is not recommended to use for larger files.

Instead modify your webpack config to include both url and file loader.

**Like this:**

```js
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
    }, 
    {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
    {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|jpg|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a limit on your url-loader of 100k bytes or something: `limit=100000` Try removing that.